# flutter new project only contains flutter.create

Tags: flutter, dart

I cant initialize a new flutter project properly on my laptop. When I clone repo in GitHub that already has flutter project, it runs without a problem in my laptop, but when I initialize a flutter project, the folder doesn't have the necessary files and folders.

[image: I initialized a new flutter project expecting to have these folder and files,] but when I initialized a project in my laptop, the folder has `flutter.create` file only. What do I have to do to initialize a flutter project that has files like in the image? [image: This is the only file created when I initialize a flutter project]

Comment: have you checked with branch you are using? sometimes we are using the develop or master branch for the main repo of the flutter project